# Ethier and Kurtz: Constructing cadlag modification of submartingales using a metric that corresponds to convergence in probability.

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

This is a statement used in the construction of cadlag modifications of submartingales in Ethier and Kurtz' Markov Processes. However, I don't quite see, or can prove why the metric below corresponds to convergence in probability.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. Let $S$ be the collection of equivalence classes of real-valued random variables where two random variables are equivalent if they are almost surely equal. Let $\gamma$ be defined on the space of real-valued random variables

$$\gamma(\eta, \xi)=\inf \{\epsilon>0: P\{|\eta-\xi|>\epsilon\}<\epsilon\}.$$ Show that $\gamma$ is a metric on $S$ corresponding to convergence in probability.

Comment: Keyword: *Ky Fan metric*.

Comment: @zhoraster I found a reference from Dudley(1976) Theorem 3.5 that defines the Ky Fan metric as $k(X,Y)=E(d(X,Y)/(1+d(X,Y))$. But I don't know how to show that this metric is equivalent to the one above. Can you give me a reference that shows the above is the desired metric?

Comment: Yes, sometimes they call Ky Fan metrics anything which corresponds to the convergence in probability. Most books leave the proof of the metric property as excercise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof consists of definition chasing. Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables, and let $Y$ be a random variable. For brevity write $$E_n:=\{ \epsilon>0 : P(|X_n-Y|>\epsilon)<\epsilon\}.$$ Note that each $E_n$ is a *ray*: if $\delta\in E_n$ then $\delta'\in E_n$ whenever $\delta'>\delta$. Argue that the following are equivalent:

1. $\gamma(X_n,Y)\to0$
2. $\inf E_n\to0$
3. For each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $\inf E_n \le\epsilon$
4. For each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $\epsilon\in E_n$
5. For each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $P(|X_n-Y|>\epsilon)<\epsilon$
6. $P(|X_n-Y|>\epsilon)\to0$ for each $\epsilon>0$

To prove (3) $\Rightarrow$ (4): given $\epsilon$ as in (4), you need to apply (3) with a different (smaller) $\epsilon$, say $\epsilon/2$.

Aside: Some authors use (5) as the definition of convergence in probability.

To prove the triangle inequality, write $a:=\gamma(X,Z)$ and $b:=\gamma(Z,Y)$. Argue that for every $\delta>0$
$$P(|X-Y|>a+b+2\delta)\le P(|X-Z|>a+\delta) + P(|Z-Y|>b+\delta)<a+\delta + b+\delta.$$
This implies that, for every $\delta>0$,
$$\gamma(X,Y)\le a + b + 2\delta$$
which implies $\gamma(X,Y)\le a+b$.

Comment: @takecare I've added detail on (3) $\Rightarrow$ (4). That's the trickiest one.

Comment: Thanks, I think I proved this using, but I get the same $N$ for (4) as in (3). I remember in your previous post that the $N$ is different.

Comment: @takecare It boils down to the question of whether $\inf A\le b$ implies $b\in A$. This isn't true in general (think of an open interval).

Comment: So from (3) we get for $\epsilon/2$ an $N$ such that $\inf E_n \le \epsilon/2$ for $n\ge N.$ Then for some $t \in (\epsilon/2,\epsilon)$, we get $t\in E_n$. Now using the ray property, $t \in E_n$. This is how proved it, but then I use the same $N$ for (3) and (4). Is there something wrong with this? Also, can you help me with showing the triangle inequality to show that the above is a metric?

Comment: @takecare Nothing wrong with this; the $N$ you got for (3) will be used in (4), but my point is that the $\epsilon$ you used in (3) isn't the epsilon you started with in (4).

Comment: @takecare ... and I've outlined how to prove the triangle inequality.